# What "a constant index that is untyped is given type int" means?

Tags: go

[Go specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Index_expressions) gives the rules for index expression `a[x]`:

> If `a` is not a map:
>
> - the index x must be of integer type or an untyped constant
> - a constant index must be non-negative and representable by a value of type int
> - a constant index that is untyped is given type int
> - the index x is in range if 0 <= x < len(a), otherwise it is out of range

What does exactly the third rule (a constant index that is untyped is given type int ) mean? Doesn't a valid expression `a[1.0]` contradict that rule?

Comment: *"A constant value x can be converted to type T if x is representable by a value of T"* -- `1.0` is *representable* by a value of type `int`, so NO the expression does not contradict the rule.

Comment: It doesn't contradict the second rule. But the question is about  the third rule

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every value used at runtime must have a type. If you use an untyped constant, it will be converted to a typed value such as in this example:

```
fmt.Printf("%T %v", 1, 1)
```

`1` is an untyped constant, but when passed to `fmt.Printf()`, it must be converted to a typed value. In the example above, its default type will be used which is `int`, so the above example prints `int 1`.

> - a constant index that is untyped is given type `int`

This means that if you use a constant value for the index that is untyped (it has no type), then `int` will be used when the constant is converted to a typed value.

For example:

```
s := []int{1, 2, 3}
fmt.Println(s[1])
```

Here the untyped constant `1` is used as the index, so it will be converted / used as `int`.

A counter-example:

```
fmt.Println(s[int32(1)])
```

Here `s` is indexed with a typed value `int32(1)`. This is valid because `int32` is an integer type.

The rule just says that if you use an untyped constant, then it will be given `int` type, and not `int32` for example.

This may seem obvious when using [integer literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Integer_literals), but not when using other kind of literals, such as [rune literals](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Rune_literals).

The following is also valid:

```
fmt.Println(s['\x00'])
```

The above example uses a rune literal `'\x00'` as the index, which is also an untyped constant but it has a different default type. Rune literals have default type `rune` which is an alias for `int32`. The quoted indexing rule states that in this case the index will be of type `int` and not `int32`.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't. `1.0` and `1` are the same number (mathematically), so the untyped constant `1.0` can be given a type `int`.

If you'll, however, try to specify `a[1.5]`, you'll get an error, since `1.5` is not an integer.

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/TeenTx6citO)

Comment: And then what a difference is between the second a the third rule? The second rule also says about representability x by a value type int

Comment: @AksenovAN The difference is that constant index may come from `const myindex int = 1` to give `a[myindex]` and untyped constant index is literally `1` in `a[1]`.